# Rails: case / when in model for update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have */models/roles.rb* where on `enum general` change I would like to update several other values:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true, inverse_of: :roles
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    before_save :set_denied, if: :general_changed?

    enum general: { seller: 1, buyer: 2, seller_buyer: 3}, _suffix: true
    #other enums follow

    private
    def set_denied
    role = Role.where("id IN (?)")
    case role.generals
        when [:seller]
        role.update_all(buyers: 'denied', discounts_policy: 'denied')
        when [:buyer]
        role.update_all(sellers: 'denied', deals: 'denied')
        else
    end
    end
end
```

I'm a bit stuck in defining case / when statements. **How can I update particular values when `:seller` or `:buyer` is selected?** Thank you for any help?

**Update**

I'm trying to do it differently like this:

```
private
    def set_denied
    role = Role.where("id IN (?)")
    case role.generals.to_s
        when :seller
        role.update_all(buyers: 'denied', discounts_policy: 'denied')
        when :buyer
        role.update_all(sellers: 'denied', deals: 'denied')
        else
    end
    end
```

however no luck so far. **Any ideas what should I change?**

**The solution**

Looks like this is final solution:

```
private
    def set_denied
    role = Role.where(id: id)
    if seller_general?
        role.update_all(buyers: 'denied', discounts_policy: 'denied')
    elsif buyer_general?
        role.update_all(sellers: 'denied', sales: 'denied')
    end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this line here: **`case role.generals`**
This should be case **role.general**
Simple spelling issue

Comment: Thank you, however it gives me this error: `NoMethodError (undefined method general for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>):`
I have `seller` selected and it should do update for particular values.

Answer (score 0):

To update many records on a single sql query with ActiveRecord, based on cases, you can use this simple gem too:

https://camilova.github.io/activerecord-update-by-case/